# remove <script> tags that contain webresource.axd as the src from a string. Using Regex replace javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `string` variable in javascript that contains HTML code in it.

I need to parse it and remove any `<SCRIPT>` Tags that contain `webresource.axd` as their source.

An example would be,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myfolder/webresource.axd?d=pfnsem3_something"></script>
```

I will need to replace that with `" "` basically empty space.

Can you please suggest how you would do that using RegEx?

Thanks I'm a newbiew to Javascript and Regex.

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

```
    // get all scripts
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

    // loop threw all scripts
    for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        // get source
        var src = s[i].src;
        // see if it contains query
        var result = src.search(/webresource\.axd/);

        // if the result is not false
        if(result != -1) {
            // remove the script
            document.removeChild(s[i]);
        }
    }
```

You can replace the remove script if you wanted to make it blank

Comment: It's not a script tag in the HTML, it's a string which contains HTML text, which contains said script tag.